# group by and average on tuples

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need a method that group by and average on a list of tuples.

Here is my current implementation :

```
  // (a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 3) -> (a, 1.5), (b, 3)
  def groupByAndAvg[T, U](ts: Iterable[(T, U)])(implicit num: Numeric[U]): Iterable[(T, Double)] = {
    ts.groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues { _.unzip._2 }
      .mapValues { xs => num.toDouble(xs.sum) / xs.size }
  }
```

Is there a better way in term of perf or simplicity ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You could do it with one mapping instead of two.
2. There's no reason for `unzip`, which generates two collections, when you only need one half of its result.  Just doing `.map(_._2)` should get you what you need.
3. Perhaps more importantly, if you plan on accessing the values repeatedly, you would want to use `map` instead of `mapValues` because `mapValues` only creates a *view* of the new map, meaning that the averaging would be recomputed on every access.
4. Finally, you don't want to declare the return type as `Iterable` since then you lose the fact that `groupBy` gives you a `Map`.

So maybe you want this:

```
def groupByAndAvg[T, U](ts: Iterable[(T, U)])(implicit num: Numeric[U]) = {
  ts.groupBy(_._1).map { 
    case (key, pairs) =>
      val values = pairs.map(_._2)
      key -> (num.toDouble(values.sum) / values.size)
  }
}

groupByAndAvg(Vector(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3)))
// res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(b -> 3.0, a -> 1.5)
```

---

### Implementing stuff yourself version:

If you do stuff like this a lot, you can define your own collection methods.  Here I define `groupByKey`, which takes a `Traverable[(K,V)]` and returns a `Map[K,Traverable[V]]`, and `avg`:

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.collection.mutable

implicit class EnrichedWithGroupByKey[K, V, Repr](val self: TraversableLike[(K, V), Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def groupByKey[That](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, V, That]): Map[K, That] = {
    val m = mutable.Map.empty[K, mutable.Builder[V, That]]
    for ((key, value) <- self) {
      val bldr = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, bf(self.asInstanceOf[Repr]))
      bldr += value
    }
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[K, That]
    for ((k, v) <- m)
      b += (k -> v.result)
    b.result
  }
}

implicit class EnrichedWithAvg[A](val self: Traversable[A])(implicit num: Numeric[A]) {
  def avg = {
    assert(self.nonEmpty, "cannot average an empty collection")
    num.toDouble(self.sum) / self.size
  }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
def groupByAndAvg[T, U](ts: Iterable[(T, U)])(implicit num: Numeric[U]) = {
  ts.groupByKey.map{ case (k,vs) => k -> vs.avg }
}

groupByAndAvg(Vector(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3)))
// res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(b -> 3.0, a -> 1.5)
```

Comment: In response to your point 2., the problem is triggered by groupBy that don't generate the structure that I need. Perhaps I have to implement a custom one ?

Comment: @Yann: I just meant that `unzip._2` is unnecessary when `map(_._2)` will do.

Comment: wow: pimp my library pattern + AnyVal to avoid unecessary instantiation + Traversable/CanBuildFrom. Code is great but difficult to read …

Comment: Let's not call it "pimp" though; let's go with "enhance" or "enrich" or "extend".  No need to bring histories of violence, exploitation, and dehumanization into coding.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way to do it (similar):

```
def groupByAndAvg[T, U](ts: Iterable[(T, U)])(implicit num: Numeric[U]): Iterable[(T, Double)] = {
    ts.groupBy(_._1)
      .map { case (k, v) =>
        (k, v.map(_._2).sum / v.size) }
  }
```

Comment: Oops looks almost identical to @dhg

Comment: :)pro : no intermediate val, con : naming variable in tuple deconstruction